# Fade one section into another on a long scrolling page

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I have a page that is broken into sections some of these sections use a jQuery plugin (Sticky-it) to stick to the browser until the section underneath scrolls up and over.

On scrolling down what I'd like to have is each section fade into the other.

HTML

```
    <section id="one">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1 class="s-heading">First Section Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Vegan yr tacos everyday carry, street art banjo cardigan four dollar toast franzen poutine wolf celiac portland keytar lo-fi. Williamsburg locavore blue bottle man bun XOXO, helvetica edison bulb.</p>
        </article>
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->


    <section id="two">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner sticky-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div>
             </div> <!-- .container -->
            </div> <!-- .inner -->
          </div> <!-- .outer -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->


    <section id="three">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1 class="s-heading">Third Section Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Mlkshk 3 wolf moon slow-carb, dreamcatcher schlitz yr chia edison bulb butcher forage yuccie four loko thundercats glossier street art. Migas tumblr knausgaard glossier leggings biodiesel. Pinterest intelligentsia chillwave, glossier cronut
                  pug poke microdosing bushwick ennui. Chicharrones +1 subway tile, fap franzen edison bulb truffaut iPhone quinoa chambray meditation food truck leggings tumeric fashion axe. Etsy bespoke tattooed, cronut aesthetic flannel microdosing iceland
                  wayfarers selfies pour-over. Pabst bushwick skateboard waistcoat migas, pork belly flexitarian asymmetrical echo park retro master cleanse XOXO viral lomo wolf. Kogi bicycle rights mumblecore mlkshk succulents, post-ironic beard ennui live-edge
                  man bun etsy.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->

    <section id="four">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1 class="s-heading">Fourth Section Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Small batch butcher hot chicken, literally gochujang cray organic copper mug venmo disrupt subway tile bushwick lyft. </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- .container -->
    </section>
    <!-- .section -->


    <section id="five">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner sticky-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div>
             </div> <!-- .container -->
            </div> <!-- .inner -->
          </div> <!-- .outer -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->


    <section id="six">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1 class="s-heading">Third Section Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Mlkshk 3 wolf moon slow-carb, dreamcatcher schlitz yr chia edison bulb butcher forage yuccie four loko thundercats glossier street art. Migas tumblr knausgaard glossier leggings biodiesel. Pinterest intelligentsia chillwave, glossier cronut
                  pug poke microdosing bushwick ennui. Chicharrones +1 subway tile, fap franzen edison bulb truffaut iPhone quinoa chambray meditation food truck leggings tumeric fashion axe. Etsy bespoke tattooed, cronut aesthetic flannel microdosing iceland
                  wayfarers selfies pour-over. Pabst bushwick skateboard waistcoat migas, pork belly flexitarian asymmetrical echo park retro master cleanse XOXO viral lomo wolf. Kogi bicycle rights mumblecore mlkshk succulents, post-ironic beard ennui live-edge
                  man bun etsy.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->


    <section id="seven">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1 class="s-heading">Seventh Section Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
          <p>Vegan yr tacos everyday carry, street art banjo cardigan four dollar toast franzen poutine wolf celiac portland keytar lo-fi. Williamsburg locavore blue bottle man bun XOXO, helvetica edison bulb.</p>
        </article>
      </div> <!-- .container -->
    </section> <!-- .section -->
```

SCSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700);

    $blue: #6da5ff;
    $white: #f4f4f4;

    html,
    body {
      background: $blue;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight:300;
      height: 100%;
    }

    *,
    *:after,
    *:before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    h1 {
      padding: 20% 0 0 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:2.2em;
    }

    p {
      font-size:1.2em;
      text-align: left;
      color: transparentize($white, .5);
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    section {
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      &#one {
        background: $blue;
      }

      &#two {
        height: 1000px;
        background: lighten($blue, 5);

        &.is-active {
          background: darken($blue, 5);
        }

         .outer {
          height: 4000px;
        }

        .inner {
          height: 1000px;
          background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1690/24482853472_282101f633_k.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
      }


      &#three {
        background: transparent;
        color: black;

        p {
          color: black;
        }
      }

      &#four {
        background: lighten($blue, 15);
      }



      &#five {
        height: 1000px;
        background: lighten($blue, 5);

        &.is-active {
          background: darken($blue, 5);
        }

         .outer {
          height: 3600px;
        }

        .inner {
          height: 1000px;
          background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8532/8625031423_f8af1a4d83_k.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
        }
      }


      &#six {
        background: transparent;
      }


      &#seven {
        background: $blue;
      }  

      .container {
        padding:1em;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 560px;
      }
    }
```

You can find the working demo here http://codepen.io/heavymessing/pen/WjbVNJ

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you add a div inside the section fade the content in?

Comment: Or just give opacity with css transition when the section is in viewpoint.